# Magento 2.4 product stock status not change after salable quantity become zero

Tags: magento2.4, out-of-stock, stock-status, salable

I tried the below scenario in Magento 2.4.0 version

**Anyone please try the below scenario in your Magento 2.4 version ?**

I created one configurable product and it's two simple children with 100 qty.

**Before Order place:**
I went to Admin Product Grid there are two columns Quantity and Salable Quantity.
One child product has 100 Quantity and Salable Quantity are 100

**After Placed order:**
In Admin product grid, same child product has salable quantity is 0 and quantity column shows 100 quantity and when I went product edit page it still shows `in stock` status even no backorders and Manages stock set to `yes` and I did reindex.

**Expected Result:**
when the product becomes zero salable quantity it should automatically  change stock status out of stock

**Actual Result:**
when the product becomes zero salable quantity it does not change stock status from `in stock` to `out of stock

**Anyone faces above issue in your Magento 2.4 version ?**

Comment: That is what currently works with MSI. You need modification for that.

Comment: @SohelRana it means is it bug right now ?

Comment: I also got a report from this issue from my manager last week; I might take a look at it in the week. I'll keep track of it. Default source indicate 0 quantity, but the product still shows as available in front side. Don't know if this is a m2 bug or not, but there has to be a workaround. I'll keep you updated of what I find.

Comment: @Claims ok thanks

Comment: yes. That is bug.

Comment: @NirajPatel have you generated Invoice and Shipment or that order and then check that things?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya after shipment qty column become zero I know this scenario

Comment: Usually, the stock status doesn't change until the order status is "complete"

Comment: @Hunter but when salable qty become is zero,it means product should be out of stock if product not allows back order ,so at frontend when salable qty becomes zero then magento should put out of stock message rather than display add to cart button and when customer try to add to cart product then it shows "requested quantity is not available"

Comment: one possibility of this is allow backorders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In My Project, I am using external Stock so Order Invoices & shipments not happening at Magento's end, so I need to change the inventory based on order placement.

The following module works as you expect. If the customer places the order if qty 1 then this below module made that product stock status as "Out of Stock".

This module removes or disables the inventory reservation on order placement.
You can find the order item qty decrement in order placement itself for qty & salable qty.

Magento 2 Module Source Link : https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Please check the additional notes on the reference link.

Comment: we are using MSI so we do not want to disable MSI

Comment: As far as I was aware that module doesn't disable MSI completely, but basically changes the reduction of stock on order and not on shipment. So it basically stops the reservation system happening

Comment: @elfling because of this issue at frontend it does not show out of stock message at frontend side. I just checked the Magento2.4.3 release notes and they solved issue and show out of stock message when salable qty becomes zero.check this link https://devdocs-beta.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html.

Comment: @jitendrapatel thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are some steps missing from the steps described, but the essential one is **shipping items**, if the order was placed but is still waiting to be shipped the product won't become out of stock, because it is still in your stock.

Here's a reference about the MSI workflow: [How does the Magento salable quantity calculation work for merchants?](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-does-magento-salable-quantity-calculation-work-corr%25C3%25AAa-gomes)

But if you use external systems to sync stock (as just salable items) or process your orders returns or shipments through a different system, then you need to disable the stock reservation, this module will handle it: https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/magento2-disable-stock-reservation

Comment: Only the bug is if salable qty is zero and qty is 1 so at frontend it will show add to cart button rather than show out of stock text if back order is no for that item. adobe says it fixed in magento 2.4.3 release notes but not fixed yet

Comment: Hi @NirajPatel, could you send the reference link? thanks

Comment: https://devdocs-beta.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/open-source-2-4-3.html